# is there any data structure in python which is a substitute for bitset in c++?

Tags: python, std-bitset

I have written a code in c++ like this:

```
    struct ds{        
    bitset<3> counter;
    bitset<29> encoding;
    }

    vector<ds> lists;
```

I want to have an array of ds,where each cell can store 3 bits counter and 29 bits encoding separately.
I want to write it in python.How to do it?

Comment: counter & encoding, they both're  integers?

Comment: yes...but i truncate them to 3 bits for counter and 29 bits for encoding...

Comment: **@Bhvya**, you can check this http://bitstruct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-usage. I can't answer here as I don't see answer box. Better is to check my gist available  at https://gist.github.com/hygull/36858bdd4cf7a2b3df248d5307bc7d64. Here I have written a small note regarding this bitstruct.